# ActiveRecord::ConcurrentMigrationError: with mysql2 and rails 5.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mysql2, ruby-on-rails-5.2

After upgrading to rails 5.2 from 4.2, any migration throws:

ActiveRecord::ConcurrentMigrationError: 
Cannot run migrations because another migration process is currently running.

Database adapter is mysql2

Initially I thought that it was because of some stale data in the existing production database that I was importing in the development environment. 
But the same issue was happening with a cleanly created database.

In order to get over it (as I really needed to get progress with some other issues) I had to disable the advisory lock check in the actual rails code.

Comment: ConcurrentMigrationError was added by https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/22122 and uses `GET_LOCK` (named lock)

Answer (score 3):

After many hours of trying to identify where the "locking" occurs and even creating a rails app from scratch, it turns out that the culprit was the "cast: false" line in the database.yml file. Once that was commented out, peace was restored in my rails universe and migrations started working again.

development:
  adapter: mysql2
  database: db
  username: user
  password: passwd
  host: localhost
  # cast: false

The ironic thing is that I can't even recall how that "cast: false" ended up there in the code two years ago in the first place. I vaguely remember that I put it there with a purpose. Nevertheless all tests run fine without it and so far no other symptoms in the actual app behavior either.

I hope this help someone out there who'll upgrade to 5.2 at some point.

Answer (score 0):

You can release the locking this way:

```
key = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.generate_migrator_advisory_lock_key
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.release_advisory_lock(key)
```